# Does git-clone have resume capability?

Tags: git

Does the git-clone command have resume capability? If it gets interrupted while I'm downloading a large repository will it resume if I give the same command again?

Comment: Similar question: [How to complete a git clone for a big project on an unstable connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954852/how-to-complete-a-git-clone-for-a-big-project-on-an-unstable-connection)

Comment: For **TL;DR**, find usage example in https://stackoverflow.com/q/38618885 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9268378

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, cloning cannot be resumed, if it's interrupted you'd need to start over. If you suspect that there's a good chance that your clone may be interrupted, look for a [git bundle](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/10/bundles.html) that you can download using a protocol that can be resumed. You could then use that to create the initial clone, and use the actual repository to keep up to date.

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue with a bad internet connection. So i came up with the following solution:
Created a small php file on my server to download the package as a zip file:

```php
    <?php
    $url = "https://codeload.github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/zip/master";
    file_put_contents("coco.zip", fopen($url, 'r'));
    ?>  
    
    <a href="coco.zip">coco.zip</a>
```

then download the zip file using any download manager that supports resume

Comment: I have upvoted since this idea is good. But this answer is not good for anyone who doesn't have access to any server. So you should mention this requirement in the answer.